# What is the real query behind Laravel's Model::belongsTo() method?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model

For example, let's take a look at this model in a laravel project:

```php
<?php
//...

class Post extends Model
{
   //...

   public function user()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class); // User model is previously defined
   }
}
```

Now I can get the user (author) info of a specific post:

```php
Post::find(1)->user()->username;
```

Of course laravel has to run some DB queries to get the data; and I wanna know what is the query behind this `belongsTo()` method.

Comment: can you share the post table forgain key which you are using for join with user table

Comment: @neel Generally the foreign keys are named `[table_name]_id` and primary keys are named `id` in laravel and in this case it is the same, primary key is `id`, foreign key is `user_id`.

Comment: Why did you mark that answer accepted when it does not answer your question?

Comment: @miken32 That's my fault. I'm sorry.

Comment: I know, you're the one who accepted it. I'm wondering *why* you accepted it? If you accepted it by mistake, you can change that by clicking the checkmark again. Accepting an answer that doesn't answer the question will only confuse later visitors to the question.

Comment: For the record, there are 2 queries. First is to get the `Post` model (`select * from posts where id=1`) and then another to get the `User` model (`select * from users where post_id in (1)`). It uses `in()` for cases when you select more than one `Post`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use the toSql() method to check query will run on laravel illuminate,

```
$sql = Person::query()->with('user')->find(1)->toSql();
dd($sql);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try use this

```
$result=Post::with('user')->find(1);
dd($result);
```

and look the response
belongs to is meaning to relation between tables
if the relation is one to one use belongsTo and hasOne

if the relation is one to many use belongsTo and hasMany

Comment: That will not output the **query** behind `belongsTo()` though

Comment: advise me brombeer how to learn laravel strongly